# SUSv4 like C code documentation

Tags: c, code-documentation

I'm writing a C library (on Eclipse) and I would like to generate documentation pages.
I really like the [SUSv4's HTML documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), can anyone please recommend me on a tool with a similar output?

Note: Auto documentation generation and Eclipse plug-in aren't a must.

Answer (score 1):

[doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/), have a try.

You can integrate doxygen to eclipse.
[Eclipse_Doxygen_Setup](http://www.mantidproject.org/Eclipse_Doxygen_Setup).